# DF from list of tuples encoded by first value of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of tuples where each tuple has following structure:

```
(domain, field_1, field_2, field_3,..., field_n)
```

each `field_x` has some value (string or integer) of is None. The `domain` field has a limited amount of unique values. I would like to end up with a dataframe where each column represents unique value of the `domain` and each column represents percentage of `None` values in `field_x` per domain.

**Example:**

```
[(domain1, None, str,  str,  None),
 (domain2, int , str,  None, str),
 (domain1, int , None, str,  str)]
```

becomes:

```
          domain1     domain2
field_1    0.5          0

field_2    0.5          0

field_3     0           1

field_4    0.5          0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert list to `DataFrame` constructor, create index by first column `0`, test `None` by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), get percentages by `mean`, add prefix `field`, remove `0` and last transpose:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(L)
        .set_index(0)
        .isna()
        .mean(level=0)
        .add_prefix('field_')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .T)
print (df)
         domain1  domain2
field_1      0.5      0.0
field_2      0.5      0.0
field_3      0.0      1.0
field_4      0.5      0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

step by step process ...

```
data = [('domain1', None, 'str',  'str',  None),
 ('domain2', 1 , 'str',  None, 'str'),
 ('domain1', 2 , None, 'str',  'str')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
df1 = df.set_index('0').isna().astype(int)
df1.columns = 'field_' + df1.columns
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print(df1)

             0  field_1  field_2  field_3  field_4
    0  domain1        1        0        0        1
    1  domain2        0        0        1        0
    2  domain1        0        1        0        0

print(df1.groupby('0').mean().T)

    0        domain1  domain2
    field_1      0.5      0.0
    field_2      0.5      0.0
    field_3      0.0      1.0
    field_4      0.5      0.0
```